# bootstrap: Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'tooltip', 'typeahead'

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to use the tooltip, typeahead, datepicker features of bootstrap. But I keep getting these errors in the console!

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'tooltip'
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'typeahead'
```

This is how my imports look like:

```
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.8.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap-typeahead.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/highcharts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/exporting.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.dropdown.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.dropdown.js"></script>
```

Some sample code:

```
<a class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" href="#payments"
           rel="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Record your payments">
            <i class="icon-check icon-white"></i> Payments</a>

$("#payments").tooltip('show');
```

Similarly I have code for datepicker and typeahead.

any solution?

EDIT:

This is what I tried just now:

```
<a href="#" rel="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Tooltip on top">Test</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $("#").tooltip().tooltip('show');
});
</script>
```

But still no success. It does show the tooltip text when I hover over `Test` but the it is of the pre-historic times. Not like the ones shown on bootstrap example pages. Not cool.

So now can anyone tell where am I going wrong?

Comment: Where are you calling the methods? Can you post also that piece of code?

Comment: Problem is that #<name> reference the id of you object, and there's no object called payments. To have it work, href="#payments" should be replace by href="#" id="payments"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure the bootstrap js files are loaded correctly? And also you should initialize the tooltip plugin on the element before calling the `show` method programmaticaly:

```
<a href="#" rel="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Tooltip on top">Test</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $("a[rel='tooltip']").tooltip();
});
</script>
```

That applies to `datepicker` and `typeahead` plugins as well.

Comment: tried one example based on your suggestion. Have updated the question. Can you help now?

Comment: The code you are using is not correct. `$('#')` is not referring to the `href="#"` if that's what you thought. The `#` in a selector is used to match the id of an element. So `<a href="" id="link1">` would be matched by `$('#link1')`. In your test case you can match the `rel` attribute like so `$('a[rel="tooltip"]').tooltip().tooltip('show');`. That should do the trick

Comment: But from what I can deduct now, you don't need the explicit `.tooltip('show')` unless you want to force the tooltip to display. If you just want it to appear on mouseover you can just do `$('a[rel="tooltip"]').tooltip();` and if will be enough, as the plugin binds itself to the mouseover/mouseout events. Try this out and let me know

Comment: I've updated the answer to reflect my latest comments. That code should give you the default tooltip functionality like on the bootstrap demo page (provided the bootstrap js file is loading correctly)

Comment: I found out what was the root cause. The problem is cause of some kind of a conflict between `bootstrap` and `HighCharts` plugins. I am using HighCharts plugin to display some charts on the same page. And when I removed the HighCharts code, the bootstraps features started working fine and there were no errors related to bootstrap. Will start a new thread to know about the conflict between these two. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 9):

I just ran into this problem and my issue was that I was accidentally including jQuery twice.

Comment: Wouldnt this be like two versions or jquery rather?

Answer (score 0):

I can see the bootstrap-tooltip.js doesnt exist in your script tags.

```
<script src="js/bootstrap-tooltip.js"></script>
```

Comment: I don't think that's necessary as the tooltip plugin should be included in the `bootstrap.js` file

Comment: i guess these all js files are all included in bootstrap.js file! correct me if am wrong..

Comment: @DarkKnightFan yes all standard bootstrap plugins should be in `bootstrap.js` (that is if you did not customize the download and unchecked any of them) http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/customize.html

Comment: Yes that is correct, but maybe you customized your bootstrap.js and you forgot to include all the plugins or your needed plugins

Comment: well no i didnt customize it.. i was very well aware of this fact hence i downloaded the full version which has all the features... i even cross checked it by checking the code inside bootstrap.js. It includes the relevant plugins...\

Comment: 1. Redownload and overwrite your existing bootsrap js
2. Or, download the plugins one by one and include them except bootsrap js

Answer (score 0):

I would try putting your bootstrap scripts underneath all your other scripts. I had the same problem and it was because I had a jQuery script above my bootstrap script.